# Rewrite rule help should be simple but not for a newbie like me

Tags: string, apache, url-rewriting, rules

My oroginal url looks like this

```
http://www.example.com/showads.php?type=1
```

And this rewrite seems to work

```
RewriteRule ^listings/type/([0-9]+)/?$ showads.php?adtype=$1 [NC,L]
```

So that all I have to do is type www.example.com/listings/type/1 and it goes to the original url

My problems comes when I add one more parameter to the original url like this

```
http://www.example.com/showads.php?type=1&clearfilters
```

I have tried several combinations of rewrites but none of them work.

The last one I have before giving up was this

```
RewriteRule ^listings/type/([0-9]+)/clear?$ showads.php?type=$1&clearfilters [NC,L]
```

What am I doing wrong? in that last rewrite? Your help is appreciated.

Thanks

JT

**Better Explanation**

Thanks for the reply. However,that still does not work.

Let me try to explain what happens

If I were to type this url

```
http://www.example.com/showads.php?adtype=3&clearfilters
```

I get the expected results. And here is an explanation of it's use

A user clicks on various links on the site and each link sets a different session variable. Over the span of a few clicks there could be 5 or 6 session variables set.

If one was to submit this url without the clearfilters

```
http://www.example.com/showads.php?adtype=3
```

You would be setting a session variable for adtype to 3

So now we would have the adtype session variable and possibly a few other set

When you submit this url with the clearfilters set

```
http://www.example.com/showads.php?adtype=3&clearfilters
```

The page unsets all the existing session variables and sets only the adtype session to 3.

Having said that, I am looking for a rule where i could just clean up the url and type something like:

```
http://www.example.com/listings/type/3/clear
```

to do the same as the ugly url.

Maybe there is a better way. I am all ears.

Thanks

JT

Comment: `However,that still does not work` - Please explain. After adding the RewriteRules (given in my answer), does it reach showads.php? For debugging, add `print_r($_GET)` at the top of `showads.php`. What are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question if you want the same replacement URL regardless of whether you have or not have the `/clear` part of the URL.

If you want the same replacement URL with or without `/clear`, you can use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^listings/type/([0-9]+)(/clear)?$ showads.php?type=$1&clearfilters [NC,L]
```

If you want the `clearfilters` parameter in the replacement URL only when the typed URL has the `/clear` part, you can do this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^listings/type/([0-9]+)$        showads.php?type=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^listings/type/([0-9]+)/clear$  showads.php?type=$1&clearfilters [NC,L]
```